# apns-client how to give it the passphrase in my code?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, passphrase

I am using apns-client (Note: not apnswrapper, so please don't close it as duplicate)

I am able to send push notifications with bypassing the passphrase.
But i want to use passphrase to make it secure. 
I can't understand from the example on where to add the passphrase in the code

http://apns-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apnsclient.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

con = session.get_connection("push_production", cert_file=key_path,  passphrase=pphrase)